# how to retrieve first row first column (first cell) value from sqlite db in android application?

Tags: android, sqlite, cell

I have worked on sample application for insert the data into SqliteDb and try for get the first row first column value from the database(first cell value).
I have implemented code for store the data into data base as follows:

```
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

 //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
"create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
+ KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null, "
+ KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null);";
```

to insert the data

```
public long insert(String content1, String content2){

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT1, content1);
contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT2, content2);

return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}
```

from the above code i can able to save the data in db but how can i get the last inserted KEY_CONTENT1 value from the same DB?

please any body help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `insert()` is the row id you just created. Use that to query for the `KEY_CONTENT1`. This would be the saves way (much more secure than a temporary variable to store the value of `KEY_CONTENT1`)

Comment: i would like to get the value from db not from variable

Comment: Than query the database with the return value as a where condition.

Comment: so whats the difference between your answer and mine?

Comment: That your answer queries the database for the last inserted row id, which is not thread safe as there might be another insert between the first insert and the query for this id. The row id is already there! Why should someone query for it again? This is a possible point of failure and should not be done.

Answer (score -1):

you need to run query to fetch last inserted row id and then use that id to retrieve the row to get your desired column:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid();
```

or try doing this:

```
SELECT KEY_CONTENT1 FROM Your_Table_Name WHERE KEY_ID IN (SELECT last_insert_rowid());
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, but still -1 as this is not a good way to do it (not thread safe operation). You should work with the row id that was returned with the `insert()` statement. Therefore the -1 stays.